# Keras CNN/LSTM Error

Tags: neural-network, keras, cnn, lstm

I'm trying to train a CNN/LSTM classifier that I found online but keep running into the following issue. How do I fix it?

[image]

[image]

I'm not sure how to reshape the data to properly get the dimensions to work. The model is defined as follows for reference:

[image]

Please let me know how to get this to work, I've been stuck on it for hours!! Thanks :)

Comment: Don't use screenshots for code and errors. Always copy paste them here, so other users can try to replicate your problem and help you.